# Principal component analysis printing

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

I am attempting to run a principal component analysis but am having trouble printing my principal components. Is there a method to do so or should I just interpret what is plotted on my graph? Below is what I have so far:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(X_train)


def myplot(score,coeff,labels=None):
    xs = score[:,0]
    ys = score[:,1]
    n = coeff.shape[0]
    scalex = 1.0/(xs.max() - xs.min())
    scaley = 1.0/(ys.max() - ys.min())
    plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley, c = y_train)
    for i in range(n):
        plt.arrow(0, 0, coeff[i,0], coeff[i,1],color = 'r',alpha = 0.5)
        if labels is None:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, "Var"+str(i+1), color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
        else:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, labels[i], color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')

plt.xlim(pca_data[:,0].min(), pca_data[:,0].max())
plt.ylim(pca_data[:,1].min(), pca_data[:,1].max())
plt.xlabel("PC{}".format(1))
plt.ylabel("PC{}".format(2))
plt.grid()

#Call the function. Use only the 2 PCs.
myplot(pca_data[:,0:2],np.transpose(pca.components_[:,0:2]))
plt.show()

print(pca.components_)
pc_columns = [X_train.columns[i] for i in pca.components_[0].argsort()[::-1]]
```

Comment: from the docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html : Attributes:
`components_` ndarray of shape (n_components, n_features)
Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data. Equivalently, the right singular vectors of the centered input data, parallel to its eigenvectors. The components are sorted by decreasing explained_variance_

Comment: Maybe you can use plt.quiver from matplotlib We cannot run your code without the X_train array

Comment: It's unclear. What do you want exactly? The ```pca_data```(the return of the ```fit_transform()```) contains the principal components or scores.